# Checkbox IsChecked property when checkbox is used into combobox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have bound `IsChecked` property to `GridMetricChecked` property but then the problem is when I set `IsChecked` to `true` via ViewModel then all items in checkbox are selected. I want only one item to be checked or unchecked. I am not getting how to do that.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0,13,0,12"  Width="100" 
    ItemsSource= "{Binding PieChartScriptSource, Mode=TwoWay}"  
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
    IsEditable="True" ToolTip="{localization:Translate FiledToolTip}" Grid.RowSpan="2">

    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate  >
        <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding }" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
          IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.GridMetricChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have binded IsChecked property of CheckBox with a property contained in a view model. So all checkboxes are pointing to the same property and hence the behavior you are getting. Instead you should create a property in a model, i.e the type of item in your ItemSource (PieChartScriptSource in your case). For example if each item in PieChartScriptSource collection is of type Class ABC then that means  that DataContext of your each ComboBox Item will be of type Class ABC and thus you have to make a Boolean property in Class ABC that represents ISChecked state of your check box.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for help but pieChartScriptSource is of type observablecollection<string> so I am not able to implement your solution.

Comment: Then you can't use string.  Create a wrapper class around the string and add a bool property like IsSelected to it.